# Why trying to insert an object into an array within a for loop results in an empty object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Although I have been using Javascript for a very long time, I am self-tought; so I guess I have some pretty big weak spots, I am happy to hear about them :-).

I am manipulating data to provide an array of objects with arrays within them to create data visualisations; but as I go through various loops I find that inserting objects into arrays is not working as expected

I have tried both using `object[descr]` and `object.descr` and the object appears correct in the console, but when I push it into the empty array it appears as just `{}`

There are a number of counters (more than just the `for` loop ones) as these match with two other arrays (`TransArray` is a largish array of strings and values that should populate `DataPiePie` which is initially populated like this:

```
[{name:"O", value:"30"},{name:"A", value:"60"},{name:"E", value:"10"}]
```

I am trying to insert children into each of the objects (which will then have children of their own up to

```
for (i = 0; i < DataPiePie.length; i++) { //for each core pie series
  iTransCol = i + 1;
  for (j = 0; j < NumberOfPies; j++) { //for each level of pie after the core
    jTransArraySer = j * 2 + 2;
    jTransArrayVal = j * 2 + 3;
    if (i == 0) {
      rangelow = 1
    } else {
      rangelow = UsedUpRows2[i - 1][j] + 1
    }; //  StartStep = UsedUpRows2[i][j] - rangelow;
    EndStep = UsedUpRows2[i][j]
    for (z = rangelow; z < EndStep + 1; z++) {
      var ChildrenObj = {};
      ChildrenObj = {
        name: TransArray[jTransArraySer][z],
        value: 5
      };
      LowChildren.push(ChildrenObj);
    }
    switch (j) {
      case 0:
        DataPiePie[i]['children'] = LowChildren;
        break;
      case 1:
        DataPiePie[i]['children']['children'] = LowChildren;
        break;
      case 2:
        DataPiePie[i]['children']['children']['children'] = LowChildren;
        break;
      case 3:
        DataPiePie[i]['children']['children']['children']['children'] = LowChildren;
        break;
    }
    LowChildren.length = 0;
  }

}
```

I want this:

```
[{name: 'O', value: 30, 
children: [
    {name: 'X', value: 30, 
    children: [
        {name: '1',value: 18, 
        children:[
            {name: 'Z', value: 18,}, {name: '2',value: 12,}
        ]}
    ]}
]},
```

...

I get:

```
[{{name: 'O', value: 30, children:[{children:[{children:[{children:[{}]}]}]}]
```

Note: I get object children appear in `LowChildren` (empty series of objects), which was really unexpected for me... I fear there might be two problems at play here: how I insert the object into the array `LowChildren` and the switch statement

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] and show what `DataPiePie` is, or at least a usable snippet? It's not really clear what this code is supposed to do, even with expected output (which is nice). Consider using recursion to replace something like `case 3: DataPiePie[i]['children']['children']['children']['children']`, which should raise a red flag.

Comment: I know it's not the issue, but: consider using [tag:javascript] standard notation vor variable naming. Variable names start with lowercase letters and class names start with uppercase letters.

Comment: You don't seem to define almost any of the variables you are using here, and you seem to reset the `LowChildren` to a length of 0 after assigning them (and you assign the reference, instead of a copy). My huge problem with this code is that there seems to be no logic to this thing (your `switch (j)`) seems to be a hack to push things at the "right" place in your output object but I really doubt the read-ability, maintainability of this code. Also, mind sharing any data for your intermediary variables?

Comment: @Icepickle  I thought I might be assigning the 'LowChildren' as a reference (I will try '.slice(0)' to fix that; somehow did not think of using slice until you raised it). I think this will turn out to be correct answer; will test and let you know.

Comment: Thanks @ggorlen for the advice on recursion, I actually could not quite figure how to drill into an infinite levels of children (and as the output of this is a donut within donut chart and can't fit more than 5 I fell back on the switch statement); but if you can point me in the right direction it would help me greatly :-)

Comment: @DanyBoy the next children are always the children of the current one ;)

Comment: @DanyBoy please supply a complete example. Do one with the code snippet thingy that SO has, and see to that it runs (that way you know you have given us all the info we need). Like what is `NumberOfPies` and
`UsedUpRows2`?

Comment: I have just changed the reference to the array as suggested by @Icepickle; to a Array.slice (0) and tah tah; everything works
I wish I had asked earlier, I have spent over 8 hours on this...

Comment: Thanks @Icepickle, I think I understand, something like this (I am confident the below would not work as is, it's just to confirm I understand the general direction):
'
tempObject = object;
for(i = 0; i<levels; i++){tempObject = tempObject.child}
DO WHAT NEEDED TO tempObject
'

Comment: Instead of using `slice()` to copy it, use `LowChildren = [];` to empty it instead of `LowChildren.length = 0;`